# How to insert value in aspx webpage textbox from windows form c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I want to insert text in the aspx webpage textbox programatically using c#.
Can anyone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some more background? ASPX is used in web pages, while Windows Forms is used in desktop apps, so what kind of app are you developing?

Comment: If you want to get an answer you should explain the problem in more detail like What exactly are you trying to do. What have you tried. What problem are you facing

Comment: i am developing an app which is used to download the file programatically from website

Comment: I have seen a person called sharrok who have asked the question which i need so i want insert date in text box and click go button and click link excel link to download programatically

Comment: but according to my question i want to go step by step so please can anyone please say me How to insert text in aspx webpage textbox programatically.

Comment: problem is not at all stated correctly, and no efforts towards it. so its fit to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case as your need are u need to first study the html design of the page in which u want to add the text value.

Using webbrowser control you can load the page u want in your app and do what you want.

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("Page URL")  //Url of the page to be loaded
```

After loading the page you can fill up the text box by their Id name

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Textbox1").SetAttribute("value","YourVAL")
```

After filling up the needed textbox you have to now press the submit button

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click")
```

Contact if you have any doubt

Answer (score 1):

Use [WebBrowser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) to load the page and fill form fields. Something like

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();  
string target = "https://www.website.com/page.aspx";  
browser.Navigate(target);
browser.Document.GetElementById("txtBoxId").InnerText = "New text";
```